# Finding if the time is before or after another time with .datetime

Tags: python, datetime, if-statement, time, between

so I have a column of data in a dataframe which is time in .datetime, in HH:MM:SS.  I just want to check if the time is in the first or the second shift, I have this code shown at the end but I keep getting the error:

**TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable**

Anyone got any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
if df_data_time(df_data_time['Time']).between('00:00:00','11:59:59') == True:
    df_data_time['Time'] = 'Shift 1'
if df_data_time(df_data_time['Time']).between('12:00:00','23:59:59') == True:
    df_data_time['Time'] = 'Shift 2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for pd.Series.between_time():

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between_time.html.

But then I would recommend you to simplify your code by first setting a new column "Shift" to "Shift 1" and then by Boolean Indexing change the necessary entries in "Shift" to "Shift 2":

```py
df_data_time['Shift'] = 'Shift 1'
df_data_time.loc[df_data_time.Time.between_time('12:00:00','23:59:59'), 'Shift'] = 'Shift 2'
```

Comment: Thanks for the link! But I still get the same ***TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable*** error doing that

Comment: Yes, I did not notice that first; I will come back later and edit my post. Your problem is that "between" and "between_time" are both pd.Series methods that give back a Boolean Vector. So the left side of your  "statement == True" is already the Boolean. The "== True" is not necessary! Please try my second chunk of code; I will come back later to explain you where your problem is in more detail!

Comment: For the meantime, google for "boolean indexing" of a series in combination with between_time; that should help you already!

Comment: I tried doing it this way, may just be me doing it wrong as I'm new to it but I keep getting this error:
***TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex*** 
What can I do to stop this?

Comment: Can you please add a few lines of your DataFrame with the actual entries? I would like to write you something!

Comment: I'm not allowed to show you my dataframe unfortunately but I have a Date column that has the date and time in it and have converted this into a time column using:
 
```df_data_time['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_data_time['Date']).dt.time```

I've tried a few things, including converting the start time into a timestamp then to a datetime but it doesnt seem to want to work!